# Adding Field in Form for Chinese Language Support in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I added a new field in Business Account Screen for [ChineseName]. While importing from Excel, the data is inserting as ???????? instead of Chinese in the database as well as Screen. I tried to change the Attribute for the new extension field from   [PXDBString(60)] to [PXDBString(60), IsUnicode=true]. (In the Data Field Customization). The Customized Project is not able to Publish.

How can Chinese Characters get imported in new Extension Data Fields defined in any Screen ??
For Existing Fields in the Screen, the data is imported and displayed in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change declaration of the PXDBStringAttribute as follows as let us know if this resolved the issue: `[PXDBString(60, IsUnicode=true)]`